# Re-distributing RTSP stream with Windows Media Services

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rtsp, windows-media-services

We have an IP camera, that streams RTSP. It cannot take many connections, so I've setup windows media services, on one of our servers, hoping that I could use that as the access-point, for the stream.

Is it possible, somehow, to set the RTSP stream, as the source for the media services stream?
From what I've gathered, Media Services doesn't support this (go figure), but there must be work-arounds. I've tried streaming it to http with VLC, in an attempt to grab the http stream on localhost, but VLC seems to crash, whenever it grabs the RTSP stream.
I'm on Server 2008 R2 (64 bit). Running VLC on our workstations, and grabbing the camera stream, doesn't crash (XP, 32 bit).

Any ideas, on how I could get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm affraid I'll have to answer myself.
I've ended up making a MMS:// stream, with VLC player. VLC grabs the RTSP form the camera, and re-hosts as an MMS. I then grab the MMS with a silverlight app, on the webserver, and hosts it there.

I ended up un-installing media-services again.

Comment: COuld you post a small tutorial on how you did this?